# Issue with Dynamic height for Custom tableview cell UIlabel

Tags: uitableview, ios8, uilabel

I want to show `uilabel` with dynamic height in `UItableview` custom cell.i Know the following code should work.

this is written at `cell for row at index`

```
    cell.lblComment.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.lblComment.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.lblComment.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
  NSString *cellText = @"test test test test test test test test test test test";
 UIFont *cellFont = cell.lblComment.font;
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(205.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        CGRect newFrame = cell.lblComment.frame;
        newFrame.size.height = labelSize.height;
        cell.lblComment.frame = newFrame;
        cell.lblComment.text = cellText;
        [cell.lblComment sizeToFit];
```

this is written at height delegate method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSString *cellText = @"test test test test test test test test test test test";
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(255.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

   return labelSize.height + 70;
}
```

Strange it is returning single line,I tried by printing lable frame height it is correct but it's not showing up on simulator.

I tried by increasing the height in xib same code working fine. I am not sure here what's wrong with assigning height for label.Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I got resolved with this simple replacement.May be this will helps to others.

```
CGSize labelSize;
    if ([cellText respondsToSelector:@selector(sizeWithAttributes:)])
    {
        labelSize = [cellText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cellFont}];
    }else{
        labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    }
```